# Use the iterator inside the closure of "any" being called on the iterator

Tags: rust, iterator, closures, borrowing

Take a look at this function:

```
fn pair_repetition(input: &String) -> bool {
    let mut pairs = input.chars().skip(1).zip(input.chars());
    pairs.any(|(a, b)| pairs.clone().skip(1).any(|(c, d)| a == c && b == d))
}
```

This function is checking if a pair of characters repeats in a string (in a non-overlapping fashion).

Now, in the last expression, I'm using `any` on `pairs` and passing a closure which attempts to clone the original iterator `pairs`. But the compiler of course doesn't allow this because the outer `any` tries to mutably borrow `pairs` which has been immutably borrowed for use inside the closure. Here is the error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `pairs` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     pairs.any(|(a, b)| pairs.clone().skip(1).any(|(c, d)| a == c && b == d))
  |     ^^^^^^---^--------^-----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |     |     |   |        |
  |     |     |   |        first borrow occurs due to use of `pairs` in closure
  |     |     |   immutable borrow occurs here
  |     |     immutable borrow later used by call
  |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

What would be a way to achieve what I'm trying to do in a functional style? (I'm deliberately avoiding loops to get comfortable with the closure-style of things).

Comment: @ÖmerErden I don't want to check the next element only. What I want to have is basically a for loop nested within a for loop and the inside for loop starts at the current index of the outside for loop.

Comment: Hmm, even if you would solve the borrow issue this logic would not work, you need to update inner iteration  on every outer iteration, your inner iterator simply iterates once then clones itself on every outer iteration.( With this it will always return true because it will compare same indexes, for non-empty ones)

Comment: I guess this is you are looking for: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3ab0c551842347cbe3d9ea252012d1b4

Comment: @ÖmerErden yes, exactly what I wanted.